# SQL Server : how to count different records and separate as column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently using SQL Server 2016  to select from a table to output a different layout. The following table `item_stats` :

```
code_no | code_status | code_category
--------+-------------+--------------
a123    |      x      | error1
a123    |      y      | error1
a123    |      z      | error1
a123    |      x      | error1
a123    |      y      | error2
b123    |      x      | error2
b123    |      y      | error2
c123    |      y      | error1
c123    |      z      | error1
```

I'm trying using group by or even partition by but cant get a result. I would like to get the following output:

```
code_no | x | y | z | code_category
--------+---+---+---+---------------
a123    | 2 | 1 | 1 | error1
a123    | 0 | 1 | 0 | error2
b123    | 1 | 1 | 0 | error2
c123    | 0 | 1 | 2 | error1
```

Basically the result will group by the `code_no` and `code_category` and showing each `code_status` which is x,y and z as a column and show the number of occurrences within those columns.

Appreciate any help or guidance in getting the output. I have tried using group by but the layout does not split the code status as an individual column.

Thanks
A. Fai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query -:

```
select code_no,
SUM(case when code_status='x' then 1 else 0 end) as [X],
SUM(case when code_status='y' then 1 else 0 end) as [Y],
SUM(case when code_status='z' then 1 else 0 end) as [Z],
code_category 
from 
[YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
group by code_no,code_category 
order by code_no
```

With Static Pivoting -:

```
select code_no,[X],[Y],[Z],code_category
from [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] 
PIVOT
(
COUNT(code_status) for code_status in ([x],[y],[z])
)a
order by code_no
```

With Dynamic Pivoting -:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct  ',' + QUOTENAME(code_status) 
                    FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT @query = 
'SELECT code_no,'+@cols+',code_category FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
PIVOT 
(
    count(code_status)
    for [code_status] in (' + @cols + ')
) P order by code_no'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use *Aggregate function condition*, to make Pivot table.

```
select code_no,
        SUM(CASE WHEN code_status = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) x,
        SUM(CASE WHEN code_status = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) y,
        SUM(CASE WHEN code_status = 'z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) z,
        code_category 
from t
group by code_no,code_category
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3dc64/1)

**[Results]**:

```
| code_no | x | y | z | code_category |
|---------|---|---|---|---------------|
|    a123 | 2 | 1 | 1 |        error1 |
|    c123 | 0 | 1 | 1 |        error1 |
|    a123 | 0 | 1 | 0 |        error2 |
|    b123 | 1 | 1 | 0 |        error2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **`CASE`** expression.

**Query**

```
select [code_no],
sum(case [code_status] when 'x' then 1 end) as [x],
sum(case [code_status] when 'y' then 1 end) as [y],
sum(case [code_status] when 'z' then 1 end) as [z],
[code_category]
from [your_table_name]
group by [code_no], [code_category];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    code_no, 
    (select count(*) from item_stats where code_no=itst.code_no and code_status='x' and code_category=itst.code_category) as x,
    (select count(*) from item_stats where code_no=itst.code_no and code_status='y' and code_category=itst.code_category) as y,
    (select count(*) from item_stats where code_no=itst.code_no and code_status='z' and code_category=itst.code_category) as z,
    code_category
from item_stats itst
group by code_no, code_category
order by code_no, code_category
```